# Prime Checker in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is a program that will take in user's desired number and check whether or not it is a prime using 'mod' (%).

I have figured out the logic of it, as using the range function to limit the times it repeats and using mod to state if any number has a remainder of zero (except for one and itself), then it must be a prime number.

```
number = int(input("Please type in your number"))

prime = ""
for a in range (2, number):
    if number % a == 0:
        prime = prime + "This is not prime"
        break
    else:
        prime = prime + "This is prime"
print (prime)
```

One of the biggest problem is that for some numbers (such as 49), it will display the result as 'This is primeThis is primeThis is primeThis is primeThis is primeThis is not prime'. For some other numbers, such as 65, it will sometimes mistakenly mark it as prime.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to get the correct behavior with minimal fixes:

```
number = int(input("Please type in your number: "))

for a in range(2, number):
    if number % a == 0:
        prime = "This is not prime"
        break
else:
    prime = "This is prime"

print(prime)
```

The `for-else` works so that the `else` block will run only if the `for` loop didn't get ended prematurely by the `break` statement. It's better to use this than just `if-else`, because there really is ot need to set the "This is prime" value in every single pass of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix your method, you should change to `=` instead of `+=`:

```
number = int(input("Please type in your number: "))

prime = ""
for a in range (2, number):
    if number % a == 0:
        prime = "This is not prime"
        break
    else:
        prime = "This is prime"
print (prime)


Please type in your number: 49
This is not prime
Please type in your number: 65
This is not prime
Please type in your number: 13
This is prime
```

Answer (score -2):

num = 20

if num > 1:

for i in range(2,num): if (num % i) == 0:

print(num,"is not a prime number")

print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)

break 
else: 
print(num,"is a prime number")

else: 
print(num,"is not a prime number")

output
20 is not a prime number
2 times 10 is 20

19 is a prime number

Comment: Please format your code correctly and explain the reasoning in your answer a bit. Also why did you post two different anwers?